# Scripting Support For Image Filtering in DigitalMicrograph

Tags: image-processing, filtering, dm-script

We can access a configured image filter with these functions:

- Image IFMApplyFilter( Image& unfiltered, String filtername )
- void  IFMApplyFilterInPlace( Image& unfiltered, String filtername )
- Image IFMApplyFilterToSeries( Image& unfiltered, String filtername )
- void  IFMApplyFilterToSeriesInPlace( Image& unfiltered, String
  filtername )

Is there a way to configure an image filter directly by scripting? For example, I would like to create a filter by combining default filters such as "Hanning Window" and "Combined Filter", and changing filtering parameters "Window Strength", "Outer Radius (Nyquist)" and etc..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there are currently no script commands to create or configure a filter.

Also, you might have noticed that the configured filters are stored in the global tags, but this does not help much. The tags are read-in on start-up only, and the current list of filters is written to tags on shut-down (overriding any changes).

So all that remains is to add this as a *feature request* for future GMS versions.