# Algorithm of Hanning Window in DigitalMicrograph

Tags: algorithm, imagefilter, dm-script

Since we cannot specify the "parameters" associated with the build-in filter functions in DM (see [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39049437/1302888)), I would like to write my own scripts to construct the filter I need.

However, I cannot figure out the algorithm of the "Hanning Window" used in DM, specifically the "strength" parameter (when strength=1.0, it is just a typical [Hann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_function)).

Does someone know the underlying algorithm?

Comment: I *think* the "power" is simply the "pow( x, power )" function applied to the transition curve.

Comment: Yes, the algorithm is indeed just a power function. However, there is no "pow()" function available in GMS2.x (not sure about 3.x) but it is rather easy to write one. Thanks.

Comment: While you can't do " img = img ** p" for non-integer p, you can do: " img = exp( p * log( img ) ) ". (Note that log() is the natural logarithm while log10() is the one to base-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the exact internal computation of the current filters. However, before you jump into re-creation you may want to check if the following script-command exists and works in your GMS version.

```
BasicImage IUHanningWindowFilter( BasicImage im, Number power )
```

This is not an officially supported command, but I believe it has been in the software for quite some time now.

Comment: This function is exactly what I'm looking for.